# Update Foundation For Email 2 to v2.1?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

How do I update an existing Foundation For Email 2 project to v2.1?

In the article about this new version nothing's mentioned about how to actually update an existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your package.json file to

```
“author”: “ZURB foundation@zurb.com”,
“license”: “MIT”,
“dependencies”: {
“foundation-emails”: “2.1.0”
},
```

Afterwards in terminal cd into your project folder and run: `npm update`.